How to apply useContext to a few Screen in React-Native?
I want to do something like this:
import React from 'react';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { MyStackParamsList } from './types';

import LoginScreen from '../screens/preLogin/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/postLogin/User/HomeScreen';
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/preLogin/RegisterScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/postLogin/User/ProfileScreen';
import ResetPasswordScreen from '../screens/preLogin/ResetPasswordScreen';
import EditProfileScreen from '../screens/postLogin/User/EditProfileScreen';
import useUserIdContext from '../hooks/useUserIdContext';
import { UserContext } from '../contexts/UserContext';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<MyStackParamsList>()

const AuthStack = () => {
  const { id, setId } = useUserIdContext();

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="LoginScreen">
      <Stack.Screen name="ResetPasswordScreen" component={ResetPasswordScreen} />
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ id, setId }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="EditProfileScreen" component={EditProfileScreen} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AuthStack;

But I can't. Is there any way to apply some context to a few chosen screens (and its children) without "breaking" all the code?
Thanks!
I tried the code from before and a few variations with Copilot but none of them worked...

Can you wrap the whole navigator instead of that set of screens?

Yes, but it affects to all the screen, not to exclusively to the ones I want
